# Add new column in Android sq-lite database

Tags: android, sqlite, addition

My Logic is:

Just insert a data into sqlite database on button click.I have created and it was working fine.

My Requirnment is:

I Want to add one more column to the existing Sqlite so i added manually.

what i did is i deleted the existing table in the emulator and run my code where i have query to create a new table.While Executing the code the table is not getting create

And here is my code goes:

**Here User_Id is my new column In sq-lite DB**

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Flag="I";
        if (valid_JobNo != null 
        && valid_Status != null
        && valid_Date_Time != null 
        && valid_User_Id != null

        &&valid_JobNo.length() != 0
        && valid_Status.length() != 0
        && valid_Date_Time.length() != 0
       &&valid_User_Id.length() != 0
        && Flag.length()!=0)
        {

        flagL = "T";
        dbHandler.Add_Tracking(new Tracking(valid_JobNo,
        valid_Status, valid_Date_Time,valid_User_Id,flagL));
        Toast_msg = "Not Connected To Internet.\nData inserted in Sqlite DB successfully";
        Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
        Reset_Text();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast_msg = "Sorry Some Fields are missing.\nPlease Fill up all.";
            Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
        }
```

DB Handler .java

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Cargonet";
private static final String TABLE_Tracking = "CargoTracking";

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_JobNo = "JobNo";
private static final String KEY_Status = "Status";
private static final String KEY_User_Id = "User_Id";
private static final String KEY_Flag = "Flag";
private static final String KEY_Date_Time = "Date_Time";
private final ArrayList<Tracking> Tracking_list = new ArrayList<Tracking>();

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_Tracking_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Tracking + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_JobNo + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_Status + " TEXT," + KEY_User_Id + " TEXT," + KEY_Date_Time + " TEXT," + KEY_Flag + " TEXT "+ ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_Tracking_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Tracking);
// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}

public void Add_Tracking(Tracking Tracking) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_JobNo, Tracking.getJobNo()); // Tracking JobNo
values.put(KEY_Status, Tracking.getStatus());
values.put(KEY_User_Id, Tracking.getUser_Id());
values.put(KEY_Flag, Tracking.getFlag());// Tracking Phone
values.put(KEY_Date_Time, Tracking.getDate_Time());
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_Tracking, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

Tracking Get_Tracking(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Tracking, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    KEY_JobNo, KEY_Status, KEY_Date_Time ,KEY_User_Id, KEY_Flag}, KEY_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Tracking Tracking = new Tracking(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),(cursor.getString(5)));
// return Tracking
cursor.close();
db.close();

return Tracking;
}

Tracking Get_TrackingF(String Flag) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Tracking, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_JobNo, KEY_Status, KEY_Date_Time ,KEY_User_Id, KEY_Flag}, KEY_Flag + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(Flag) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Tracking Tracking = new Tracking(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), (cursor.getString(5)));
    // return Tracking
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return Tracking;
    }

public ArrayList<Tracking> Get_Tracking() {
try {
    Tracking_list.clear();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Tracking;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Tracking Tracking = new Tracking();
        Tracking.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

        Tracking.setJobNo(cursor.getString(1));
        Tracking.setStatus(cursor.getString(2));
        Tracking.setDate_Time(cursor.getString(3));
        Tracking.setUser_Id(cursor.getString(4));
        Tracking.setFlag(cursor.getString(5));
        // Adding Tracking to list
        Tracking_list.add(Tracking);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return Tracking_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("all_Tracking", "" + e);
}

return Tracking_list;
}

public int Update_Tracking(Tracking Tracking) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_JobNo, Tracking.getJobNo());
values.put(KEY_Status, Tracking.getStatus());
values.put(KEY_Date_Time, Tracking.getDate_Time());
values.put(KEY_User_Id, Tracking.getUser_Id());
values.put(KEY_Flag, Tracking.getFlag());

// updating row
return db.update(TABLE_Tracking, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(Tracking.getID()) });
}

public void Delete_Tracking(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_Tracking, KEY_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
db.close();
}

public int Get_Total_Tracking(Tracking Tracking) {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Tracking;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
cursor.close();

return cursor.getCount();
}

Tracking Get_Flag(String flag) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Tracking, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    KEY_JobNo, KEY_Status, KEY_Date_Time ,KEY_User_Id , KEY_Flag}, KEY_Flag + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(flag) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Tracking Tracking = new Tracking(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4) , (cursor.getString(5)));
    cursor.close();
db.close();

return Tracking;
}
public Cursor getListItem() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void addListItem(ArrayList<String> tracking_data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Tracking.java

```
public class Tracking {

// private variables
public int _id;
public String _JobNo;
public String _Status;
public String _Flag;
public String _Date_Time;
public String _User_Id;

public Tracking() {
}

public Tracking(int id, String JobNo, String _Status, String _Date_Time,String _User_Id, String _Flag) {
this._id = id;
this._JobNo = JobNo;
this._Status = _Status;
this._Date_Time = _Date_Time;
this._User_Id = _User_Id;
this._Flag = _Flag;
}

public Tracking(String JobNo, String _Status, String _Date_Time,String _User_Id, String _Flag) {
this._JobNo = JobNo;
this._Status = _Status;
this._Date_Time = _Date_Time;
this._User_Id = _User_Id; 
this._Flag = _Flag;
}

public int getID() {
return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
this._id = id;
}

public String getJobNo() {
return this._JobNo;
}

public void setJobNo(String JobNo) {
this._JobNo = JobNo;
}

public String getStatus() {
return this._Status;
}

public void setStatus(String Status) {
this._Status = Status;
}

public String getDate_Time() {
return this._Date_Time;
}

public void setDate_Time(String Date_Time) {
this._Date_Time = Date_Time;
}

public String getUser_Id() {
return this._User_Id;
}

public void setUser_Id(String User_Id) {
this._User_Id = User_Id;
}

public String getFlag() {
    return this._Flag;
    }

public void setFlag(String Flag) {
    this._Flag = Flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code. I am not (and mostly nobody is) going to read all that.

Comment: You mean in Main Activity.java?. Other two java is imp for my post. now i will post button click only from main activity sir..

Comment: *"Relevant"* means only code that matters. How do you know which code matters? Well, removing code until you have minimum code that reproduces your problem. This is called an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I've skimmed though most of your code but I think what you are really asking is "how do you update a database?"

first you will change the `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` function to create the model database structure with the new column you want to add. Then change the `DATABASE_VERSION = 1` to `DATABASE_VERSION = 2`. If the new version is greater than the current version run the drop tables and `onCreate` function again.

Also, a side note on `public void Add_Tracking(Tracking Tracking)` change that to `public void Add_Tracking(Tracking tracking)` and change all references to the variable to start with lowercase as well. I'm not sure if that would cause any issues with your code but its confusing to read when both the local variable and class have identical names and formats.

Comment: Change your DATABASE_VERSION to equal 2

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what Your problem is or which option You want to choose to add a new column, but usually, to add new columns You have to check the database version and upgrade it and add the new column. You can do it in the onUpgrade():

```
     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

       // If you need to add a new column
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
             db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+table_name+" ADD COLUMN "+new_column_name + "  INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
         }
     }
```

Instead of Integer Default 0, You can also use TEXT NOT NULL or any value else You want to put into the database column.